# Create a Console Screen Buffer using Java

Tags: java, console

I would like to use the console as a "screen" in order to display a game of tic-tac-toe without printing a new board below the previous one at each turn.

I have seen some examples of how to do this in C++ on Windows using the `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer` function.

Any way to do this with Java (on a mac)?

Comment: Sure, put your game into a Java GUI and open it through the console. In my opinion it would be far easier than creating your own cross-platform console terminal. [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) and even [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt).

Answer (score 0):

One thing I used for this in my early java days was printing a large number of return characters: 
Ex. `for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){System.out.println("\n");}` to make the previous board "disappear". 
From what I have seen there's no easy way to clear the console screen like c++ does because of the limitations between java and the console.
 if you want something a little different I'd recommend learning how to work with and use GUIs and I believe you'd be able to move a substantial amount of your code over and have it work mostly the same.

Comment: You are right in that a GUI would make this easier and I have worked with it before but I don't want to dilute the code of my project (the tic-tac-toe is just an example of what I would need to be able to do) with GUI stuff. The focus should lie on an algorithm and not a user experience in this case.

Comment: @BenHeckmann I agree, I have actually done a project where I made tetris from "scratch" (aka using a video as a reference) and I wanted to make it purely in the console but with live input I couldn't do without a GUI to read the inputs. So I get where you're coming from and when I did my tetris project in the console I ended up using the **"put in a bunch of return lines"** to make the screen clear better.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is the alternative screen buffer, it's usually used for terminal applications to return to the main terminal screen after the application has finished. You can simply switch to an alternative screen by using ANSI escape codes.

Java example:

- To enable the alternative buffer

  ```
  System.out.print("\033[?1049h");
  ```
- To disable the alternative buffer

  ```
  System.out.print("\033[?1049l");
  ```

This will be only helpful at the start and end of your application.
However you can clear the screen after each "turn" with the ANSI codes
**("\ESC[3J\ESC[H\ESC[2J")** and then print the new "screen" again.

Try taking a look at ANSI escape codes

https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797